# How do i make a button execute this method

Tags: java, android

This may be a super easy answer but my app crashes when I push the button. This is the method im trying to run the the click of a button:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

I made sure I have :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and here is my activity main:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="postData"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the method should be

```
public void postData(View v)
```

Another thing, You can not perform network operation in main UI thread. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead

Comment: Eh. Beat me by ten seconds :P +1

Comment: @RaghavSood at the same time.. why you deleted that, pointed when upvoting yours

Comment: I missed out on the UI Thread networking issue. Your answer already had that information. Didn't make sense to duplicate it :P

Comment: Im not sure I understand how to use the Async Task, can you explain?

Comment: @BluGeni , go to the link I have posted, There is a nice example :)

Answer (score 0):

The application may be crashing because connecting to internet is not allowed on UI Thread.  So, you should AsyncTask to post data to HTTP Web Services.

More details can be found in this discussion ([How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception))

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `asynctask` for network related opearation or create a new thread.

```
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

If not you will `NetWorkOnMainThreadException`.

On button click

```
        new PostData().execute();
```

Then

```
      class PostData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
      {
              @Override
              protected void doInBackground(Void... params)
              {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

                    try {
                        // Add your data
                       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                       // Execute HTTP Post Request
                       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       }
                       return null;           
              }   
      }
```

For more info check the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html